# Any freeware or open source tool to populate database with some dummy values

Tags: mysql, database, populate

I have somewhere around 30 tables used in my web application. I need to populate those tables with some dummy values during development. Later once the application is ready we will have the real data. Are there any tools to populate database tables in MySQL with dummy values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

http://www.generatedata.com/

I've been meaning to look at it for a while, but never quite got round to it.

Comment: This is similar to what I have been looking for. I was thinking about a tool that would read the schema automatically and generate the data values for the tables. But I can live with this. Great tool. Thanks Mike

Answer (score 0):

you could use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) to easily manage your database.
The community edition is free.

Answer (score 0):

With Jailer you can export data [to an SQL script](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/quicktour.htm) which can traverse foreign key constraints to include all data needed to maintain referential integrity.

Here is a screenshot from the Jailer website demonstrating the data export:

[image: Jailer export]

Comment: My requirement is to populate the database tables with dummy values and not exporting the data. I am not sure, if the feature is available with Jailer

Answer (score 0):

I'm 10 years late, but I created a [tool](https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/populate_data) that handles the creation of tables and populate them with fake (but valid) data. Maybe it was not exactly what you wanted but if anyone is interested you may give it a try.

[image]